# Restarting Jasper Server changes the Scheduled Time of the Jasper Reports

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler, jasperserver

I have five reports which are scheduled to run starting from 2:00 AM (each report has a gap of 20 min). For few weeks they ran fine, but when Jasper Server was stopped for few hours and started back again, for all the reports the execution time of these reports has changed to 16:20 PM.

This is happening on PROD env. Gong forward we have to restart the jasper every month for OS Patch, how can i stop the Scheduler to change the execution time wth every restart of Jasper Service.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this issue is ancient, but I've just installed Jasperserver 7.8 and this is still an issue. Has anyone found a way to fix this short of going into the database and resetting the trigger time (in qtz_triggers table)

If I change the time in qtz_triggers, the report runs at the specified time, but the next reschedule of the "Next Run" is again incorrect.